# match the radio button selected value with mysql in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to fetch the selected radio button value and match it with mysql database value whether it is correct or not. i am making online quiz system where user don't need to login he/she can simply open the website and can start the quiz and after 15 questions the quizans.php page should be open where all the values selected by user through radio button should be fatched and then it will be match with mysql

### mainquiz.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
extract($_REQUEST);
require_once("connection.php");
$q=mysql_query("select * from quiz ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50");

$a=mysql_fetch_array($q);


if (isset($Submit))
{
    $_SESSION['clicks'] += 1 ;
} 
else 
{
    $_SESSION['clicks'] = 1;
}

if(isset($Submit) && $_SESSION['clicks'] == 11)
{
    header("location:quizans.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

### and the html form looks like

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <table width="834" height="396" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="757" height="390"><div align="center">
        <p><strong>Question <?php echo $_SESSION['clicks'];?> </strong></p>
      </div>
          <p>
            <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $a['ques']?><br />
            <br />
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name=".$a['qno']." value=".$a['a']." />
              <?php echo $a['a']?></label>
          </p>
        <p><br />
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name=".$a['qno']." value=".$a['b']." />
                <?php echo $a['b']?></label>
          </p>
        <p><br />
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name=".$a['qno']." value=".$a['c']." />
                <?php echo $a['c']?></label>
          </p>
        <p><br />
              <label> </label>
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name=".$a['qno']." value=".$a['d']." />
                <?php echo $a['d']?></label>
          </p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p>
            <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

i don't know how to fetch the values which user select and match it with mysql database in quizans.php page

the mysql database looks like :-
[database name -- quiz_db 
table name--- quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWsSr.jpg)

what should be code for this page

Comment: mysql is deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="<?php echo  $a['qno'] ; ?>" value="<?php echo $a['a'] ; ?>" />` use something like this for each radio input